# Azure Web Platform Installer cmdline fails to download predefined feeds

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, web-platform-installer

Using the WebPICmd downloaded from the link on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433092.aspx) today (2012-12-03), I'm getting some error messages whenever I try to install any package.

Apparently it fails to download the predefined Microsoft feeds (I'm not giving any custom feeds via cmdline args). Googling for those messages gives me zero results.

Here's the output:

```
PS E:\approot\bin\webpicmdline> .\WebpiCmdLine.exe /Products:whatever

The software that you obtain using the Web Platform Installer Command Line Tool is licensed to you by its owner.  Micros
oft grants you no rights for third party software.

Successfully loaded metadata from feed https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml
Failed to Load feed: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml
More than one product with productId 'DotNetNukePro'
Failed to Load feed: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml
An item with the same key has already been added.
Failed to Load feed: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml
Failed to resolve OS List with id: 'OSList_VS2010_Shell'
Failed to Load feed: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Installing via GUI PI works fine.

I've tried deleting all temporary feed XML files, deleting cache via a button in GUI PI, nothing seems to fix the issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI works because you're probably using the Web Platform Installer 4.0. The command line tool you downloaded is still the old 3.0 version.

Simply use the 4.0 command line tool and everything will work correctly. You can find it in the Web Platform Installer installation directory (it comes with the GUI application): **C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebpiCmd.exe**

Comment: Thanks, man! I wish Microsoft updated their download links since Windows has no package manager… You know any way to download cmdline only from somewhere?

Comment: Only for the preview version: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233753. If you want the final, I think you'll need to install the full WPI first and take WebpiCmd.exe and Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.dll.

Comment: Microsoft's love to non-Windows developers is as usual. Well, thanks a lot anyway, I have almost ripped all my hair out with this.